# Display length of string only if greater than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone please help with the Excel formula to count the string length in a particular cell and display the count only if the string length is greater than zero?

I hope this formula can "NOT" display anything if the cell to be counted is blank.

Comment: Hi Rajster - welcome to stack overflow! While your question is well phrased, it would probably be better if you included some information about what you already tried and what failed, or gave unexpected results. Otherwise it would look like a solve-my-homework kind of question, which probably won't get answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEN` in an `IF` statement. For example, `=IF(LEN(A1)=0, "", LEN(A1))`

Comment: Would it be possible to add another condition that says do not display if count is above a certain value, to the same formula? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Rajster sure thing, I like nested IF's like ```=IF(LEN(A1)=0, "", IF(LEN(A1)>99, "", LEN(A1)))``` but you can also take a look at the ```IFS``` function

Comment: No problem. Just FYI, another option is to use conditional logic like ```=IF(OR(LEN(A1)=0, LEN(A1)>99), "", LEN(A1))```